# Android Power consumption of a method

Tags: android, android-emulator, battery, batterymanager

For a research project I need to measure the power consumption of some functionality. So I would like to measure the power consumption of a method. For example: method `computeSomething()` needed x `microampere-hours`. Is this possible? If yes, how?

I tried to measure the remaining battery capacity in `microampere-hours` and the remaining energy in `nanowatt-hours` before and after execution with the `BatteryManager`. But this isn't accurate enough. Is that even possible to do it?

this is what i tried:

```
mBatteryManager.getLongProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER);
```

EDIT:

for sure it's the emulator which don't consume energy and that's why I get a consumption of 0. Is it possible to simulate power consumption with the android emulator or do I need a real phone?

Comment: ah stupid thing, for sure it's the emulator which don't consume energy and that's why I get a consumption of 0. Is it possible to simulate power consumption with the android emulator or do I need a real phone?

Comment: You better should edit your original question with this details to get accurate answers ;)

Comment: Rather than trying to measure the power used, I suggest you measure the CPU time used. You have no idea what else has been using power while your method executed, so trying to measure power by remaining battery capacity won't give you accurate data. But power used by execution is proportional to CPU cycles so measuring that will give you a proxy for power consumption.

Comment: Unfortunately, CPU time/processes is not going to given an accurate measure of power because energy used is not linear with regards to CPU cycles in modern processors. Power usage per cycle is dependent upon how much of the circuitry is being used, and that varies greatly depending upon the instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would measure the energy used (because that's what you want and not power).

1. Shutdown (or don't use) everything I can, including network, cell, USB, etc.
2. Disable any power saving features on the phone
3. Log any data you get on the phone's file system (vs through the USB or wireless)
4. Wrap the program in a large loop that makes its runtime at least a few seconds, perhaps a few minutes
5. Run the test program you just made many times (>=16 times for statistical significance)
6. Measure the phone at rest over the same amount of time and collect the energy used.

ANALYSIS: (and you need to do this)

1. Check on the statistical deviation (std dev) of both your function run and the "at rest" run. If the std dev is large, something else is going on that is using energy.
2. Find out the resolution of BatteryManager. Just because the field is labeled in nWatts doesn't mean the hardware measures it at that resolution (and it probably doesn't). The people who develop a data structure want that structure to be useful on a lot of hardware and for the foreseeable future. Thus they make the field measure in something very small (e.g. nWatts) even if most hardware can only measure at best, say, in tenth of watts.
3. If possible, use a hardware interposer between the battery and the phone to measure energy/power directly. This gets around the uncertainty in the implementation of BatteryManager.
4. Just to be safe, you might also find out how long of an integration window the BatteryManager uses for measuring power. These measurements usually involve a moving window for computing averages.
5. An emulator isn't going to give you any useful information. Emulators test functionality and little else. Even a rough measure of performance is very iffy.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a similar App before but is used to evaluate the power consumption of each Application. But as far as I know, the Google's battery static API evaluate power consumption according to each UID, both hardware and software. I think you can find more information by looking into the source code of Android, especially for BatterySipper.java and BatteryStatsHelper.java.

For emulator, Android system uses power_profile.xml as reference to calculate the power consumption. This file is usually modified by manufacturer. Maybe it's not included in emulator.